# how to find open set for topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{a,b\}$ with the indiscrete topology $T=\{X, \varnothing\}$. How to find the open set for $T$? I'm confused that the open set for a topology $T$ must be its subset. Therefore, the subsets for $T$ could be $\{a\},\{b\}$ and $\{a,b\}$? 
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

Each member of a Topology on a topological space is called its open sets. If your topology is $\{T,\emptyset\}$, the your open sets are $T,\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

You already know the open sets. A topology is by definition the collection of *all* open sets. So the only open sets in $X$ are $X$ and $\varnothing$.

You're right that open sets must be subsets of $X$. But $X$ is a subset of itself, and the empty set is a subset of any set, so $\varnothing \subseteq X$.

Answer (score 0):

A topology $\mathcal T$ on a set $X$, is a collection of subsets of $X$ that satisfy three stipulations. **The open sets are precisely the elements of the collection $\mathcal T$, (The subsets of $X$ that are in the collection).**

(i) $X\in \mathcal T$, $\emptyset \in \mathcal T$ 
(ii) If $U \in \mathcal T$ and $V\in \mathcal T$ then $U\cup V \in \mathcal T$. That is, $\mathcal T$ is closed under "arbitrary unions" 
and finally: 
(iii) If $U_1,U_2,\dots U_n \in \mathcal T$ then $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} U_i \in \mathcal T$. That is that $\mathcal T$ is closed under "finite intersections"

For your example, since any arbitrary union of elements of $\mathcal T = \{X,\emptyset\}$ will be either $X$ or $\emptyset$, (ii) is satisfied for this collection of subsets of $X$.

(i) Obviously (i) holds. 
There is a similar argument for (iii). It is easy to see that any finite intersection of sets from $\{X,\emptyset\}$ will result in either $X$ or $\emptyset$. Thus $\mathcal T = \{X,\emptyset\}$  satisfies the three stipulations for being a topology on a set $X$. It is called the "Trivial topology" or "Indiscrete topology", as you so noted in your question.

Comment: Your answer is very concrete. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: So if the topology is (1,2) on IR , its subset is itself, which means (1,2)?